# Access google api with user's username and password

Tags: ios, oauth, google-api, cordova, oauth-2.0

I am working on a mobile app that is a [planner app for ios](http://kck.st/11hRglY).
I have many people that are requesting the feature to integrate with google calendar.  I looked at the calendar api's and they look very straightforward.  The challenge is getting the user authenticated.  The user experience that I want is for the user to login to google using their username and password, then I will access the calendar API.  I have been looking at the [oauth2 google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) and it gives examples for redirecting the user to google.   I would prefer not to redirect the user for authentication.  Is this possible?  Let me make it clear that I absolutely don't want to store the users' usernames and passwords.

Comment: For Android there is an [account manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) maybe there is an equivalent on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, it's no longer possible (or at least will not be possible in the near future).

ClientLogin allowed this type of functionality, but it's been over a year now since it's been deprecated and according to [this article](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) Google will not support it after one year.

Google now recommends embedding a web browser in the application, which for iOS is done by using the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html).

Answer (score 1):

[ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) let's you do what you want, but that auth method has been deprecated.

You have to use oAuth now, and it really doesn't make sense for you to implement your own UI with oAuth; it breaks the whole "trust" model.